# Report Builder 3.0 Exporting to Excel

Tags: export-to-excel, reportbuilder3.0

I have created a layout that works just fine.  However, when I export it to Excel, the data starts in column C.  Another person in our department has created a different layout.  When they export their reports to Excel, the data starts in column B.  I've looked at both layouts and don't see any difference.

I would like to get my reports to display data in column B as well so we are consistent.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the answer is that the table in your report does not start at exactly the 0,0 position. Select it and in the Properties panel on the right hand side scroll down to Position, make sure location says "0cm, 0cm".

Comment: Thanks..........That was the issue.  I hadn't paid attention to that before since I was assuming that the users would be looking at the report on line.  In this particular case, the user was going to export the results to Excel.  Thanks for your help......